# Command line 7zip issues when encrypting headers

Tags: command-line, header, 7zip, encryption

I'm creating an zip file using 7zip from the command line during my build process. using a command like this:

7z.exe a -pPassword "..\sot.zip" .

This command works correctly and I'm able to see an encrypted file as expected.  Now when I add the capability to encry0pte the headers

7z.exe a -mhe=on -pPassword "..\sot.zip" .
7z.exe a -mhe+   -pPassword "..\sot.zip" .

```js
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive sot.zip

System error:
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I get "The parameter is incorrect." errors regardless of where I put them on the command line.

Is there a way to perform the encryption of headers from the command line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-mhe` is not supported in `.zip` files. For it to work, use `.7z` format

```
7z.exe a -mhe=on -pPassword "..\sot.7z"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this, and it did work:

```
7z.exe a -psecret -mhe=on C:\newfolder\a.7z "C:\folder1\back-this-up"
```